# CakePHP transfer from localhost to remote server

Tags: cakephp-2.0

I am getting an error when I uploaded the files online. Something is suddenly up with the debugkit.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in
>   /home3/beauface/public_html/cosmeticsurgeryph/inventory/app/Plugin/DebugKit/Controller/Component/ToolbarComponent.php
>   on line 179

Everything is working smoothly when I run it on localhost.

Please enlighten me :(

Answer (score 0):

Change your PHP Version to 5.3 or greater.

Because ToolbarComponent.php uses [Anonymous Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) which supports only from 5.3+